# Need unplug/plug to access at USB port ChromeApp

Tags: linux, usb, google-chrome-app, thermal-printer

I want to do a chrome-app to receive print requests. This app need to connect to a printer via USB, but I need to unplug/plug the printer when I reboot the PC in order to have access to it, why do I need to unplug/plug the printer?

I'm working on Linux, but I've tried it also on Windows and it doesn't even show up either. (on three differents computers)

After reboot I get, the following error:

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Failed to open device.

If I unplug and plug It works.

I've removed some checks to make it more readable

```
 

    function printDataToDevice(data, device) {
      chrome.usb.openDevice(device, function(handle) {
        printDataToHandle(data, device, handle) 
      });
    }

    function printDataToHandle(data, device, handle) {
      chrome.usb.claimInterface(handle, 0, function() {
        printDataToInterface(data, device, handle);
      });
    }

    function printDataToInterface(data, device, handle) {
      if(!handle)
        return;
      var info = {
        "direction": "out",
        "endpoint": 1,
        "data": data
      };
      chrome.usb.bulkTransfer(handle, info, function(transferResult) {
        chrome.usb.releaseInterface(handle, 0, function() {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          return;
        });
      });
    }
```

```
In the app manisfest:
<pre> <code>
"permissions": ["usb","storage", {
      "usbDevices": [
        {
          "vendorId": 1046,
          "productId": 20497
        }
      ]
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a situation like this, the previous attempt to use the USB device was not properly cleaned up before trying to open it again.  I would debug an ensure that print is completing and the releaseInterface is being called when you expect it to be.

Unplugging the device forces the release of the device.